# Variadic templates : Creating a compile time array

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a function that I want to use to create an array at compile time.

```
template<typename... uint32_t> 
static constexpr auto AddressArray(uint32_t... ns) { 
    return std::array<uint32_t, sizeof ...(uint32_t)>{ ns... }; 
}
```

when I use this code, I get a compiler error

```
`compiler is out of heap space.`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not simply use `constexpr std::array arr{/* some literals */};`?

Comment: That is an option. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving a pack of types, it would be better to give a type for array and pack for values:

```
template<typename T, T ...vals> 
static constexpr auto AddressArray() { 
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(vals)>{ vals... }; 
}
```

Example usage:

```
auto array = AddressArray<int, 1, 2, 4, 5>();
```

Comment: How do I specialise this only for uint32_t as the other types are not valid in this context.